# Better way to do this in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to improve my CSS and wondered if someone could take a quick look over what I have so far and explain where I could improve.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/42txfuru/

```css
.author div {
  width: 35%;
  float: left
}
.author div.img {
  width: 30%
}
.date {
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<div class="author">

  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <p><span class="vcard">Barry Rooney</span>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p class="date"><span>Today's Date</span>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You can remove `<p>` inside `<div>`

Comment: Does this belong on the Code Review site?

Comment: It's not good practice omitting the `;` at the end of the last CSS definition in a selector block. Also, I'd recommend you sort your CSS definitions alphabetically.

Comment: use clear:both after using float:left or right so you will save your code by any extra space issue.

Comment: Better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not good practice to omit the `;` at the end of the last CSS definition in a selector block. Also, I'd recommend you sort your CSS definitions alphabetically.

Then, keep your HTML as short as necessary. See my suggestions below. Don't omit mandatory attributes on elements (in this case `alt` on `img`).

```css
.author {
  font-size: 0;  /* This fixes unwanted whitespace issues */ 
}
.author > * {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px; /* resetting the font-size to what you actually need */
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 35%;
}
.author .img {
  width: 30%;
}
.date {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="author">
  <div class="img"><img src="http://placehold.it/70x70" alt="" /></div>
  <span class="vcard">Barry Rooney</span>
  <p class="date">Today's Date</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is using `.author > * {` best practice? Or is it just quicker doing it this way?

Comment: The `>` makes sure you don't have any issues with nested containers as it does what you want - it only applies to direct child elements. Since you might want to change the type of these elements at some point in the future, it's better to not define the type of element.